# GCC-C++ Cross compiler, missing libraries

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I am attempting to go through the [bare bones tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) on osdev. I would like to build my kernel using C++. When I try to compile, I get a some linker errors:

```
~/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.3.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
~/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.3.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
~/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.3.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
~/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/7.3.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I followed the instructions to [make a cross compiler](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). I am on macOS so I followed the OS X instructions, figuring that they would still be relevant.

I do realize that I am not going to have full runtime support from C++. I took a course at my university last semester on operating systems, but they setup much for us (the boot file, basic kernel functionality like putting a character on the screen, etc.) and also provided a runtime environment for us to use so I never got the opportunity to learn how to do this all on my own. I would like to build the kernel in C++ for the sake of building it in C++ and seeing how that will differ from the kernel that we build in C.

How can I build these libraries?

Comment: You probably need to add `-nostdlib`, especially if you're making a kernel (it comes with some caveats; check `man gcc`).  `libm` and `libc` are part of your libc, so you'll need to compile that.  Not sure on `crt0.o`, but my guess is either binutils or libc.

Comment: Actually, that was it. Thanks. If you add that as an answer, I can accept it, kind sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add -nostdlib, especially if you're making a kernel (it comes with some caveats; check `man gcc`). `libm` and `libc` are part of your libc, so you'll need to compile that. Not sure on crt0.o, but my guess is either binutils or libc.